# Groovy Jenkins Convert LinkedHashSet to String

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, type-conversion, linkedhashset

**Ultimate goal**:

a. Convert ArrayList to LinkedHashSet for getting unique results and then

b. convert the LinkedHashSet to String with "\n" as delimeter ie. every record on a new line. I will be applying the conversion logic in a Jenkins pipeline as well.

**What I Tried:**

1.

```
def uniqueResults = results as Set
resFile.append(uniqueResults.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
```

2.

```
def uniqueResults = results as Set
def resString = String.join("\n", uniqueResults)
resFile.append(resString)
```

**Issues:**

with 1. the string is concatenated with "," but I want every record separated with "\n"

with 2. does the thing but takes an extraneous time (~10 mins) for large records (~3000 records)

I am looking for a way to convert the Set to String but in the fastest way possible. I appreciate any links and pointers.

Comment: How about `resFile << results.unique().join('\n')`

Comment: the database independent expression `( (1..10000).collect{"item"+it} as Set ).join('\n')` that collects 10K items works fast. it means that your `results` is fetching slow...

Comment: @tim_yates `resFile << results.unique().join('\n')` works perfect and is much more readable..Also one note to Jenkins users..use writeFile (or Bash script) to write contents to a file since File() has issues with slave workspace: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/343